# How to compute Bias and Variance for the given scenarios?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, expected-value

I'm currently studying the "[Learning from data](https://work.caltech.edu/lectures.html)" course - by Professor Yaser Abu, and I do not get the "bias-variance tradeoff" part of it. Actually, the concepts are fine $-$ the math is the problem.

In the lecture 08, he defined bias and variance as follows:

$\text{Bias} = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\left[(\bar{g}(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x}))^2 \right]$, where $\bar{g}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}\left[g^{(\mathcal{D})}(\mathbf{x})\right]$

$\text{Var} = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\left[ \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}\left[( g^{(\mathcal{D})}(\mathbf{x}) - \bar{g}(\mathbf{x}))^2\right] \right]$

To clarify the notation:

- $\mathcal{D}$ means the data set $(\mathbf{x}_1, y_1), \cdots, (\mathbf{x}_n, y_n)$.
- $g$ is the function that approximates $f$; i.e., I'm estimating $f$ by using $g$. In this case, $g$ is chosen by an algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ in the hypothesis set $\mathcal{H}$.

After that, he proposed an example that was stated in the following manner:

**Example:** Let $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ and a data set $\mathcal{D}$ of size $N = 2$. We sample $x$ uniformly in $[-1, 1]$ to generate $(\mathbf{x}_1, y_1)$ and $(\mathbf{x}_2, y_2)$. Now, suppose that I have two models, $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1$.

- $\mathcal{H}_0 : h(x) = b$
- $\mathcal{H}_1 : h(x) = ax + b$

For $\mathcal{H}_0$, let $b = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}$. For $\mathcal{H}_1$, choose the line that passes through $(\mathbf{x}_1, y_1)$ and $(\mathbf{x}_2, y_2)$.

Simulating the process as described, he states that:

1. Looking for $\mathcal{H}_0$, $\text{Bias} \approx 0.50$ and $\text{Var} \approx 0.25$.
2. Looking for $\mathcal{H}_1$, $\text{Bias} \approx 0.21$ and $\text{Var} \approx 1.69$.

Here is my **main question:** How can one get these results analytically?

I've tried to solve the integrals (it didn't work) that came from the $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting in the right way which distribution is which. For example, how to evaluate $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}\left[g^{(\mathcal{D})}(\mathbf{x})\right]$ (it is the same as evaluating $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}\left[b\right]$ or $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}}\left[ax+ b\right]$, for $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1$, respectively, right?)? The random variable which has uniform distribution over $[-1, 1]$ is $\mathbf{x}$, right? Thus $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[\cdot]$ is evaluated with respect to a random variable that follows $U[-1, 1]$ distribution, right?

If anyone could help me to understand at least one of the two scenarios, by achieving the provided numbers for the $\text{Bias}$ and $\text{Var}$ quantities; it would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance,

André

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is “yes”. (Where you write “evaluating $\mathbb E_{\mathcal D}[b]$ or $\mathbb E_{\mathcal D}[ax+b]$ for $\mathcal H_0$ and $\mathcal H_1$”, $a$ and $b$ need to be computed from the data as given in the problem statement, e.g. $b=\frac{y_1+y_2}2$.)

I'll calculate the bias and variance for $\mathcal H_0$.

We have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar g(x)
&=&
\mathbb E_{\mathcal D}\left[g^{(\mathcal D)}(x)\right]
\\
&=&\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_1}2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_2}2\frac{\sin\pi x_1+\sin\pi x_2}2
\\
&=&
0\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

so the bias is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb E_x\left[\left(\bar g(x)-f(x)\right)^2\right]
&=&
\mathbb E_x\left[f(x)^2\right]
\\
&=&
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx}2\sin^2\pi x
\\
&=&\frac12
\end{eqnarray*}

and the variance is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb E_x\left[\mathbb E_{\mathcal D}\left[\left(g^{(\mathcal D)}(x)-\bar g(x)\right)^2\right]\right]
&=&
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx}2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_1}2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_2}2\left(\frac{\sin\pi x_1+\sin\pi x_2}2\right)^2
\\
&=&
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_1}2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm dx_2}2\left(\frac{\sin\pi x_1+\sin\pi x_2}2\right)^2
\\
&=&
\frac14\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't know why they're given with $\approx$, as these are their exact values.

For $\mathcal H_1$, you'll have more involved integrations, since you get $x_2-x_1$ in the denominator:

$$
a=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{\sin\pi x_2-\sin\pi x_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$

and

$$
b=\frac{x_2y_1-x_1y_2}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{x_2\sin\pi x_1-x_1\sin\pi x_2}{x_2-x_1}\;.
$$

Also, in this case you have an actual dependence on $x$, whereas for $\mathcal H_0$ the integration over $x$ for the variance was trivial since $g$ was constant.

Comment: joriki, thank you for the insights (and solution). It seems obvious now, but the part "$a$ and $b$ need to be computed from the data as given in the problem statement" elucidated a big portion of my confusion. One last thing, the problem does not mentioned it explicitly, but $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}, \cdots$ are assumed to be drawn independently, isn't it? Otherwise, I should have some additional info about the joint density.

Comment: @André: Yes, I'd think so. I assumed that in my calculations.